# Modifying PowerShell object in a function

Tags: powershell

```
function Itil
{
    $_.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25pt, style=Italic'
    $_.Text = 'Double-click to add username'
    $_.ForeColor = 'ScrollBar'
}

$Username10.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25pt, style=Italic'
$Username10.Text = 'Double-click to add username'
$Username10.ForeColor = 'ScrollBar'
```

Is there a way to pass an object into a function without having to name the object itself?

In other words, rather than repeating the same last three lines of code for each `$username` (there are 10 username textboxes), I can call a function, with the name of the object and make the changes to that object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathias provided a nice way using PowerShell filter. However, if you want to use a simple function, this should work:

```
function Set-BasicProperties
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        $UiObject
    )

    $UiObject.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25pt, style=Italic'
    $UiObject.Text = 'Double-click to add username'
    $UiObject.ForeColor = 'ScrollBar'
}


Set-BasicProperties $Username10
```

Answer (score 2):

If the input objects are all reference types you can iterate over the `$input` enumerator:

```
filter Set-UsernameFieldStyle {
    $input |ForEach-Object {
        $_.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25pt, style=Italic'
        $_.Text = 'Double-click to add username'
        $_.ForeColor = 'ScrollBar'
    }
}
```

and use like:

```
# Input all the elements that need to be styled this way via the pipeline:
$Username1,$Username4,$Username10 |Set-UsernameFieldStyle
```

Comment: Is it possible to do $username$n (where $n is an integer)?      ForEach ($n in 1..10 )
  {   
   UseSystemPasswordChar $Password$n
  }